# Convert GeoJSON geometry to new coordinate system and WKB format in python

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, well-known-binary

I have a GeoJSON like such:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "uuid": "68F15C01-20CD-4D77-954B-9483BA1D4D33",
            "name": "ABC",
            "len": "529",
            "infotype": "Restricted",
            "h1": null,
            "join": null
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [-360909.60698310119, 7600968.922204642, 0.0],
                [-361357.344715965, 7600811.951385159, 0.0],
                [-361805.08159795138, 7600654.939420643, 0.0]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I need to convert the geometry to EPSG:27700, as I've just realised I have no idea what the coordinate system above is supposed to be but I do know the placement of the features should be in the UK.

Once I've successfully done that, I'd then like the different feature geometries in WKB format using Python.
I've tried the below code but I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-360909.60698310117, 7600968.922204642, 0.0, -361357.344715965, 7600811.951385159, 0.0, -361805.08159795136, 7600654.939420643, 0.0'
```

```
# Python program to read
# json file


import json
import shapely
from shapely import wkb, wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Opening JSON file
f = open('metadata.json')


data = json.load(f)


for i in range(len(data['features'])):
    geom = str(data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'])
    newstr = geom.replace("[", "")
    newstr2 = newstr.replace("]","")
    geom3 = float(newstr2)
    g = wkb.dumps(geom3, hex=True, srid=4326)

    print(g)
```

Comment: It's not good geojson if it is not lat, lon or tells you the projection. Could it already be in 27700

Comment: @IanTurton I don't believe so as I tried to load it into geojson.io and they weren't placed were expected

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz amended

Comment: Can you ask from the data provider in what coordinate system the data are?

Comment: Well geojson.io would expect 4326 as per the standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coordinate system of GeoJSON may be EPSG:3857. You can use the following script

```py
import json
import shapely
from shapely import wkb, wkt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

# Opening JSON file
f = open('metadata.json')
data = json.load(f)

for feat in data["features"]:
    geom = LineString(feat['geometry']['coordinates'])
    
    g = wkb.dumps(geom, hex=True, srid=3857)
    
    print(g)

# OUT:
# 01020000A0110F00000300000063FA8C6D360716C19E66053BD2FE5C410000000000000000D038FD60350E16C1947EE3FCAAFE5C410000000000000000D2698E53341516C1C3771FBC83FE5C410000000000000000
```

[image]

Comment: you're correct!! It is EPSG:3857! Thank you so much for both the coordinate system and the code!